# Dependecies missing when updating to 15.04

Tags: 15.04

When I try to update to 15.04, I randomly get an error message that package xxx doesn't have the required dependecies or that a package that is needed has not been configured yet. Not only that, when the updater was at around 50%, it rebooted and I could no longer login, luckily I have a backup so I could restore.

So how would I fix this?

EDIT: Output of `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

And errors like these

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-gnome2: python-gnome2 needs libbonobo2-0 (>= 2.32.1-3~); but: Version of libbonobo2-0:amd64 on this is 2.32.1-0ubuntu5.
```

`apt-cache policy python-gnome2 libbonobo2-0`

```
python-gnome2:
  Geïnstalleerd: 2.28.1+dfsg-1.1
  Kandidaat:     2.28.1+dfsg-1.1
  Versietabel:
 *** 2.28.1+dfsg-1.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.28.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libbonobo2-0:
  Geïnstalleerd: 2.32.1-0ubuntu5
  Kandidaat:     2.32.1-0ubuntu5
  Versietabel:
 *** 2.32.1-0ubuntu5 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: can you add the output with that error to your question please as so we can see what's happening exactly.

Comment: The question is, how would I fix this?

Comment: we cannot foretell we need output or name of the pkgs anything

Comment: to solve your question , you need to provide error message . We can't assume what is "xxxx"

Comment: XXX was the package name, I can only remember that one of the packages were init and systemd. I'll re-run the upgrade and copy the errors.

Comment: I ran update-manager again, this time instead of getting the GUI I got this: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-gnome2:
 python-gnome2 needs libbonobo2-0 (>= 2.32.1-3~); but:
  Version of libbonobo2-0:amd64 on this is 2.32.1-0ubuntu5.

Comment: ^Cmichael@Michael-TV:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty

Comment: `grep -r 'vivid' /etc/apt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you messed up your Ubuntu installation I recommend a clean install of Ubuntu.

In this special case to fiddle around with a repair attempt will not make very much sense.

Fortunately the new edition 15.10 is just around the corner, it will be released tomorrow.

As Ubuntu 15.04 will only be supported until January 2016 you should wait this one day.

Alternatively you can stick with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, for which you have a working backup.

Comment: Wuuuut, tomorrow? Awesome! Didn't know that, thanks.